# Is this unifiable? SDLNF Derivation of the Generic Goal.

Tags: logic, unification

I found a problem which is a definite program problem and ask to obtain all SDLNF derivations of the generic goal.

$Product(x,y) ← Quantity(x),Rate(y)$

$Rate(x) ← Sub(x)$

$Quantity(a)$

$Quantity(b)$

$Quantity(f(a))$

$Rate(f(a))$

$Rate(f(b))$

$Sub(f(f(a)))$

(There ain't no meaning of what names imply. I just used some words for P,Q,R,S)

and the General goal is $← Product(x,f(x)),¬Quantity(f(x))$

So I started to solve this.This is how I started,

$G0$ : $← Product(x,f(x)),¬Quantity(f(x))$

$C0$ : $Product(x,y) ← Quantity(x),Rate(y)$

$G1$ : $← Quantity(x),Rate(f(x)),¬Quantity(f(x))$

$C1$ : $ Quantity(a)$

$G2$ : $← Rate(f(a)),¬Quantity(f(a))$

$C2$ : $ Rate(f(a))$  -- Here it is not unifiable to remove $ Rate(f(a))$ and obtain $G3$ . I mean if it was something like $ Rate(f(d))$ then I can remove it by using Rate(f(a)) and unifier($σ$) for that would be $ σ={d/a} $. But here $ σ={a/a} $ which is according to the theory is not unifiable.

So For me this seems like does not have a SDLNF refutation. Am I missing something? Does this have a refutation?

Comment: It seems to me that G2 is: $\leftarrow Rate(f(a)),¬Quantity(f(a))$.

Comment: Oh yeah. That was a mistake. Otherwise is there any problem?

Comment: WVhy you cannot go on with G2 and C2 to derive G3: $←¬Quantity(f(a))$ ?